# Function for looping response

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, lodash

I have a problem with how to loop and store in an array.

```
    /** Model to display response*/
    export class ResultsData {
        id: number,
        name: string,
        startDate: string,
        endDarte: string,
        startTime: string,
        endTime: string,
        city: string,
        country: string
    }

    /**Response upon service call*/
response = [
{ 
    startDate: '04/05/2018', 
    endDate: '05/05/2018' , 
    personDetails : [ { id: 5, name: 'kumar', timeDetails: [{ startTime: ’09:22pm’, endTime: ’08:33’}, { startTime: ’01:22pm’, endTime: ’01:33’}] }, { id: 4, name: 'vishal', timeDetails: [{ startTime: ’09:22pm’, endTime: ’08:33’}, { startTime: ’01:22pm’, endTime: ’01:33’}] } , { id: 2, name: 'dinesh', timeDetails: [{ startTime: ’09:22pm’, endTime: ’08:33’}, { startTime: ’01:22pm’, endTime: ’01:33’}] }],   
    locationDetails : [{city: 'new york', country: 'us'}, {city: 'los angeles', country: 'us'} ]}
]


    /**Component.ts*/
    tableData : Array<ResultsData> = []
```

For every person in `personDetails`, I want to push his details (EG. name and id) and the last index of time details, last index of location details into an array.

```
Expected output: 

tableData = [ 
{ id: 5, name: 'kumar', startDate: '04/05/2018', endDate: '05/05/2018', startTime: ’01:22pm’, endTime: ’01:33’ city: 'los angeles', country: 'us'},  
{ id: 4, name: 'vishal', startDate: '04/05/2018', endDate: '05/05/2018', startTime: ’01:22pm’, endTime: ’01:33’, city: 'los angeles', country: 'us'}, 
{ id: 2, name: 'dinesh', startDate: '04/05/2018', endDate: '05/05/2018', startTime: ’01:22pm’, endTime: ’01:33’, city: 'los angeles', country: 'us'} 
]
```

Comment: ```locationDetails``` is an array, what should happen if it has multiple elements?

Comment: it should be taking the last index of both time and location details for each person and push. I have made slight change i.e. added time details too. I couldn't figure it out exactly how can i do that.

Comment: Please review the example once more, ```timeDetails``` appeared _inside_ ```personDetails```, and there is no trace of "New York" in the example output.

Comment: Yes, my bad I have that kind of json only with those time details inside person details and also about New york i.e. I just want last index of both location array and time details array.

Comment: @tevemadar Sorry it was my mistake there is a slight change, each person has time details property. Can you help me out please

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try constructor approach with mapping your `personDetails` to `tableData`:

```
class ResultsData {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    startDate: string;
    endDate: string;
    startTime: string;
    endTime: string;
    city: string;
    country: string;

    constructor(item) {
      Object.assign(this, item);
    }
}

tableData = response[0].personDetails.map(item => new ResultsData ({
  id: Number(item.id),
  name: item.name,
  startDate: response[0].startDate,
  endDate: response[0].endDate,
  startTime: item.timeDetails[item.timeDetails.length - 1].startTime,
  endTime: item.timeDetails[item.timeDetails.length - 1].endTime,
  city: response[0].locationDetails[response[0].locationDetails.length - 1].city,
  country: response[0].locationDetails[response[0].locationDetails.length - 1].country
}));
```

Comment: How can I just have last index of both location and time details for each person.

Comment: @BhachiKumar You have timeDetails property within personDetails array, do you think it's a valid json? It is even impossible to run your response sample in the console (SyntaxError). I advise you to review the format of the `response` before continue.

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake there is a slight change, each person has time details property. Can you help me out please

Comment: @BhachiKumar your can check in stackblitz or plunker or typescript playground

Comment: @dhilt I am getting startTime is undefined and exiting the loop and giving no results. Can you please help me out. TIA